# Start as a fresh device with Firebase SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing Firebase (Auth, Realtime DB and Firebase to be exact) in an iOS app using the official SDK. The users are authenticated as anonymous users and the rest depends on successful authentication.

The issue is that I'm having trouble testing the "fresh install" scenarios as the SDK seems to assign the same UID(user id) even after the app is uninstalled or Firebase files are programatically removed from the /Documents folder.

This is causing me problems as the devices who had the previous installation behave differently from the fresh devices, making it difficult to debug the initiation process of a "freshly downloaded" app.

Removing the user using the Firebase console doesn't help either as the users can still maintain access as long as the token is valid and it seems like the token remains valid even after the app is removed and re-installed.

Any ideas or guidance on how to deal with the issue?

Comment: Do you have exact reproduction steps and code to show?  A user id should not survive an app uninstall. User IDs should never be reassigned.  Also, tokens should not continue to work, after the user account is deleted, for an hour after they were last refreshed.

Comment: It's nothing exotic, I'm using XCode 10, the device is on iOS12 and I installed the latest pods for the SDK. The app is built primarily with SpriteKit, when the scene is loaded an authentication as an anonymous user is performed as described on the Firebase SDK. The tokens do invalidate after a while but the same UID is assigned after a re-install, as if the app was never deleted.

Comment: On a fresh device, Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid  is nil until the device is authenticated but on a re-install it returns the same UID even if there's no internet connection at all.  I was able to obtain a fresh UID on the same device after updating the pods and I think after cleaning some non-essential files to recover space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround to problem you are facing. Every time you detect a fresh install, you need to force sign out previous user.

1. Store user id to `UserDefaults` each time you anonymously authenticate user.

   ```
   UserDefaults.standard.set("ENTER_USERID_HERE", forKey: "user_ID")
   ```
2. Every time your app launches, check if user id is set to `UserDefaults`.

   - If user id exists, then it is not a fresh install as UserDefaults resets each time app is deleted.
   - If user id doesn't exist, then it is a fresh install. If this is the case you need to sign out user to solve your issue.

     ```
     if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user_ID") == nil {
          let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
          do {
              try firebaseAuth.signOut()
          } catch let signOutError as NSError {
              print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
          }
     }
     ```

**Note: This is a workaround and you should only use it while testing.**

Comment: Great! This worked perfectly.  I'm still curious though, how does the Firebase maintain the UID between installs straight out of the XCode(not iCloud backups). I think I've read that UID is generated using the current date/time but maybe it's the device id(Haven't Apple took measures against it?). Hmm, maybe I should try to reset the advertising ID.

Comment: I believe Firebase stores user session related information in device's Keychain Services. Data stored in Keychain persists even after deleting the app. Check more about this here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services